# Make a box with pill like border-radius on one side and fixed border-radius on other side

Tags: css

How can I make a box that has fixed border radius size (`10px`) on right and rounded corners on other size without hardcoding the border-radius on right so it works for all size?

#### Bad

[image]

#### Good

[image]

Note how the the good one has complete rounded corner on the left side.

With fixed height it's easy:

```
.pill {
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;

  border-top-left-radius: 50px; /* 50% of height */
  border-bottom-left-radius: 50px; /* 50% of height */

  border-top-right-radius: 10px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;

}
```

But with **dynamic width and height**, I don't know how:

```
.pill {
  height: 10vh;
  border: 1px solid black;

  /* how to make left corner to be rounded like a pill for any width and height? */
  border-top-left-radius: 50px; /* 50% of height */
  border-bottom-left-radius: 50px; /* 50% of height */

  border-top-right-radius: 10px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;

}
```

**Some answers are trying to fix this with large `em` or `rem` based radius numbers. That will not do it because it impacts the border-radius on the right.**

Comment: JSBin http://jsbin.com/giqoxipete/edit?css,output

Answer (score 0):

I think it can solve your problem

```
border-top-left-radius: 50em; /* 50% of height */
border-bottom-left-radius: 50em; /* 50% of height */
```

Some examples:

```css
div {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-top-left-radius: 50em;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 50em;
  border-top-right-radius: 10em;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 10em;
}
.pill1 {
  height: 10vh;
}
.pill2 {
  height: 100vh;
}
.pill3 {
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="pill1"></div>
<br>
<div class="pill2"></div>
<br>
<div class="pill3"></div>
```

Comment: That's not a solution.

Comment: Did you test that? Make a Codepen demo and show it to us

Comment: Look at other corners. It's impacting border radius on right.

Comment: Please use em instead of px also

Comment: Thanks for trying but I don't want `em` on other side.

Comment: Still no consistent border radius size on the right

Comment: in this example left part works with em and right side works with px